# Researchers Bypass ASLR Protection on Intel Haswell CPUs

Tags: hardware, aslr

See [Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/researchers-bypass-aslr-protection-on-intel-haswell-cpu-509460.shtml) and [research paper](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~nael/pubs/micro16.pdf). Could we somehow prevent this attack on various OS?

Comment: Have you read and understood the "Software Mitigations" part of the paper? What questions remain after reading this part?